# Declaring method header of templated class prototype method

Tags: c++

Header file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class A_Type> class Queue
{
    public:
        Queue(int = 10);
        Queue(const Queue<A_Type>&);
        ~Queue();
        Queue& operator=(const Queue&);
        bool enqueue(A_Type);
        bool dequeue(A_Type&);
        bool empty() const;
        bool full() const;
        bool clear();
        A_Type * getData();
        bool operator==(const Queue&) const;
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Queue<A_Type>&);
    private:
        int max;
        int front;
        int rear;
        A_Type *data;
};
```

My attempt at declaring the method in Queue.cpp (The error shows up on the first line):

```
Queue<class A_Type>::Queue(const Queue<A_Type> &q)
{
    front = q.front;
    rear = q.rear;
    max = q.max;
    data = new A_Type[max];
    data = q.data;
}
```

Eclipse is throwing the error:

```
forward declaration of 'class A_Type'
```

And I'm not really sure what that means nor how to fix it. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for a template method definition outside of the class declaration.

```
template <class A_Type>
Queue<A_Type>::Queue(const Queue<A_Type> &q)
```

That will take care of the error you are getting now.  You may find that you have a problem, though with trying to define template methods separately in a CPP file. See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)